# angular 6 return result of forkJoin subscribe (rxJs 6)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

**Simple case and OK:**

```
const observables = [];
for (let i = 0; i < this.originalData.length; i++) {
      observables.push( this.dashboardService.getDetails(this.id1[i], this.id2[i])
       };

forkJoin(...observables).subscribe(dataGroup => {
    console.log(dataGroup.id);
});
```

console is `1 2 3 4 5`

**More complexe case for me and KO:**

```
private todo(foot) {
    const observables = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.originalData.length; i++) {
      observables.push( this.dashboardService.getDetails(this.id1[i], this.id2[i])
    };

    forkJoin(...observables).subscribe(dataGroup => {
      console.log(dataGroup);
      // How to put all dataGroup id in foot.param ?
    });

    return this.dashboardService.getFoo(foot);
}
```

the code execute this:

```
return this.dashboardService.getFoo(foot);
```

before this:

```
console.log(dataGroup);
```

How to wait end of subscribe and add/mofify all dataGroup id in foot.param before retun (at the end)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `todo` function should be async itself, so it should return an `Observable`:

```
private todo(foo): Observable<any> {
    const observables = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.originalData.length; i++) {
      observables.push( this.dashboardService.getDetails(this.id1[i], this.id2[i])
    };

    // notice that dataGroup is an array of latest value of all observables
   return forkJoin(observables).map((dataGroup: any[]) => {
      // do whatever you want to foo before calling the function
      // remember you need to also merge if getFoo returns an observable as well
      // but I assume it doesn't
      return this.dashboardService.getFoo(foo);
    });
}
```

Comment: it's not necesary forkJoin(...observables), just forkJoin(observables)

Comment: This use of `forkJoin().map` tells me...  error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<[any, any, any]>'.

Comment: @KimGentes It has changed since rxjs 6. You need to use `forkJoin.pipe(map(...))`